# Laravel composer update fail with mbstring on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, mbstring

I think my case is weird and I don't know exactly what my problem. I got this error message when I do composer update:

`the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system`
My environment:

- Windows 7 x64
- PHP 5.6 (XAMPP x32)
- Laravel 5.4.*
- **php_mbstring already installed in C:/xampp/php/ext and set enable in php.ini**
- Restart webserver and even restart Windows several times

BUT in the end, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case is Windows command line permission. 
Just have to run the command line with **admin permission**.